# Google Identity Toolkit - prevent safari popup and use webview instead

Tags: ios, google-identity-toolkit

Is there anyway I can force the identity providers signin screens to open in a webview inside my own iOS app. At the moment, it always opens safari (default behavior).

Answer (score 0):

There is serious security concern if the identity providers page is rendered in a webview. End users would have no way to be sure that they are signing into the authentic identity provider. Also the mobile app can read the user input in the webview, which will expose the user's password at the identity provider to the app.

Comment: good point. I guess I was wondering how apps like airbnb are able to pull up their google logins in what appears to be a webview: step 1: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uhkywuw6irjz7il/Screenshot%202015-11-25%2012.40.50.png?dl=0 step 2: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fz9bfuwcn2lu07j/Screenshot%202015-11-25%2012.41.52.png?dl=0